# Does a multi programming language parsing / function extraction toolkit exist?

Tags: go, language-agnostic, code-analysis

I'm looking for a way to extract function names and their definitions from multiple different programming languages. I would like to avoid writing extractors by hand as I want to support about 15 programming languages.

Is there a library / program that could be used to achieve this? Searching didn't give me any useful results.

I'm currently using go for my application, but I don't mind handling this in a different language.

The app itself will be open-source so proprietary solutions are not desired.

Comment: I suspect your question is going to get closed because SO hates tool recommendation questions.  So much that  they kill these questions.  They insist they be asked at SoftwareRecommendations (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), although the closer probably won't tell you that.   I answered anyway because I think the very existence of SR means that people do want recommendations and separating them is pointless.

Comment: @IraBaxter: I'm not sure separating them is *pointless*, but having links from here to SR is certainly useful, if they're going to be separated. So closing is OK, but not deleting....

Comment: If I understand correctly, tool recommendation questions get closed because in abundance of all available software usually there isn't a single right answer. I hope this question won't get closed because I don't think there are many different tools available to solve the problem I have.

Comment: @JanLikar: If you believe that, then Software Recommendations is equally pointless.  Yes, recommendations are opinions.  If they come from experts, they are reasonable opinions.  But often the first question is "does it exist?".

Comment: @IraBaxter That's a good point, actually.

Comment: Sorry to be the one to put the nail in the coffin with a close vote but I don't make the rules here (which I also don't always agree). The problem is that these type of questions when left unclosed open the door as examples for others to show as evidence as why they can ask other subjective questions.

Comment: `I would like to avoid writing extractors by hand` The problem is that as languages evolve you have to tweak the grammar for parsing. Then the problem becomes deciding which version of the grammar to use for a language which tends to turn into a black art, think heuristics and AI.  While Ira's company would be one place I would direct one to, there software is quite expensive but from what I read worth it if you really can afford it. Edit: Note I wrote this before reading the answers, I now see Ira did add an answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity do any of the languages on your list require [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_grammar) to parse?

Comment: Before I forget. Another problem with what you seek is that while many programmers can parse context free grammars and well formed formulas, for some of the harder problems you need to use parsing techniques that many often don't know. [DMS](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/DMSLexers.html?Home=DMSToolkit) uses [GLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) while I prefer [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) with [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar).

Comment: I don't think context-free grammars would be necessary, not sure about attribute grammars, I've not heard of this term before, if I'm being honest.

Comment: Technically you don't need a CF *parser*; any parser you can build will do the trick.  What you will discover, very painfully, is if you try to parse complex languages like C++ (and these days, COBOL, C#, Java, ...) without using a context-free parser that your life will be hell trying to bend the parsing machinery to match the real code out there in world.   ANTLR has many language parsers, most of them broken because of this.  My company's DMS uses GLR (fully context free) parsers, and we've build some 50 full language front ends with an extremely modest team; I offer this as a proof point.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to **extract** functions instead of parsing the source files then the traditional way to do this is using [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags).

Most unix-like OSes either comes with ctags already installed or has ctags available. However, ctags is not a single program. Like other unix utility programs it may have started as a single program but by now there are several implementations of ctags.

The most widely used implementation is probably Exuberant Ctags. It has a fairly good coverage of languages but it does not handle a lot of more modern languages (for example, it does not natively handle go). It currently supports around 40 languages: http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html

Universal Ctags is a more recent project and I believe started as a fork of Exuberant Ctags. Universal Ctags supports a lot more languages (including go): https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/tree/master/parsers

Ctags generates a `tags` file containing information of all the objects found. The actual format of the `tags` file depends on the implementation of the ctags program but they generally contain what type of object was found (variable, class, function etc.), the file it was found in, the line number and for Exuberant Ctags the search term you need to find the object (sometimes a string literal sometimes a regexp).

Comment: I personally use ctags in my own text editor as a cheating way to do intellisense - you do need to run ctags separately but if my editor finds a `tags` file it will load it so you can do things like go to definition etc.

Comment: Thank you, this is just perfect!

Comment: Ha, I spoke to soon, I can't find a way to get the end line number of a function.

Comment: Yes. Ctags won't do that. It only idenfies "names" and what those names mean and where they are located. But you can still use it as a starting point because you now know where the function starts. For most languages you can then just count braces - though that won't work in Python and is not reliable for Javascript or Java if the programmer used short arrow functions.

Comment: True, but counting braces would fail if there were unmatched braces in comments. Then I would also need to have language-specific handling of comments. Not impossible to write that, but maybe a bit painful.

Comment: I don't really care for lambdas and short arrow functions, so that's not an issue.

Comment: Ah. Sloppy parsing.  Looks OK until you try it at scale.  Then you get enough noise in the results to make it pretty disenheartening.  Tools need to work better where humans don't.  Scale is the obvious first place they have a chance at doing better; people are lousy at scale.

Comment: Some parsers of u-ctags cat extract "end" line with `--fields=+e` option. https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/man/ctags.1.html?highlight=end%20field#extension-fields

Answer (score 1):

This isn't easy to do, because each language has different rules about legal syntax and what constitutes a "function".

I can offer my company's  [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=StackOverflow) as a way to do this.  We've fought the battle of parsing multiple languages (maybe all of your 15, see [list of languages supported by DMS](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/index.html?site=StackOverflow)) and building various kinds of fact-extraction machinery.   You'd have to customize it for the specific facts you want to extract.

[Yes, its proprietary.  OP added a not-proprietary requirement after I answered this question.  Other folks might not have this constraint.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would prefer an open-source solution (question updated). I will, however, consider it if I don't find anything appropriate. DMS looks really nice, btw.

Comment: Not that I would buy the software if PostScript were on the list but when I was learning to parse PostScript it had some peculiarities so different from other languages like Java, Lambda Calculus, Prolog that I actually learned a few more tricks.